# IS there a way to mock SVGTextElement to be able to test function, using Jest, that uses getBBox() to measure text?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, jestjs

I wrote simple function to measure texts before I decide what font size should I use.

```
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
const text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
svg.appendChild(text);

interface HeightAndWidth {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

interface MeasureProps {
  label: string;
  fontFamily: string;
  size: number;
  fontWeight?: number;
  lineHeight?: number;
  letterSpacing?: string;
}

export const measureText = ({
  label,
  fontFamily,
  size,
  fontWeight = 400,
  lineHeight = 1,
  letterSpacing = '0',
}: MeasureProps): HeightAndWidth => {
  text.setAttribute('font-size', `${size}px`);
  text.setAttribute('line-height', `${lineHeight}px`);
  text.setAttribute('font-family', fontFamily);
  text.setAttribute('font-weight', `${fontWeight}`);
  text.setAttribute('letter-spacing', letterSpacing);
  text.textContent = label;
  document.body.appendChild(svg);

  const { width, height } = text.getBBox();

  return {
    width,
    height,
  };
};
```

It's pretty straightforward and it works nice but I'm having problem writing unit tests for this. The problem is that while working in browser it doesn't work during tests and throws an error

> text.getBBox is not a function.

I tried mocking `window.SVGTextElement` but it keeps throwing error that it's prototype is missing 241 more properties. Even tried it's type but the error stays, and error with missing `getBBox` repeats.

Is there a way of testing code like this?

```
import { measureText } from '../measure';

interface MockSvgTextElement {
  prototype: {
    getBBox: () => { height: number; width: number };
  };
}

describe('animateNumber', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    window.SVGTextElement = {
      prototype: {
        getBBox: () => ({
          height: 20,
          width: 100,
        }),
      },
    } as MockSvgTextElement;
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    document.body.appendChild(p);
    console.log('window.SVGTextElement', window.SVGTextElement);
  });

  it('should measure text', () => {
    const textSize = measureText(
      {
        label: '12345',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        size: 20,

      }
    );
    expect(textSize).toEqual({});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`getBBox` can be used for the `SVGGraphicsElement` type only.

Create an `<svg>` element under `body` and then append a `<text>` under `svg`.

Then you can call `getBBox().width` for the `text` element

Comment: Why not on SVG elements themselves? Works in the browser